# save php stdClass object in mysql table field

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to save php stdClass object in mysql table field with out change object?

this is my object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [product] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 413860
            [name] => SB25
            [description] => Array
                (
                    [0] => AMD Athlon 64 3700+
                    [1] => 2x RAM 1024 MB DDR
                    [2] => 2x HDD 320 GB SATA
                    [3] => RAID Controller 2-Port SATA PCI - 3ware 8006-2LP
                )

            [traffic] => 20 TB
            [dist] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Rescue system
                )

            [arch] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 64
                )

            [lang] => Array
                (
                    [0] => en
                )

            [cpu] => AMD Athlon 64 3700+
            [cpu_benchmark] => 568
            [memory_size] => 2
            [hdd_size] => 320
            [hdd_count] => 2
            [datacenter] => 1
            [price] => 21.01
            [price_setup] => 0.00
            [price_vat] => 21.01
            [price_setup_vat] => 0.00
            [fixed_price] => 1
            [next_reduce] => 0
        )

)
```

I want to save this object in mysql and retrive it later...
can any one help me?
thanks

Comment: What do you want to save?

Comment: You could json_encode it and save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to **[serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)** your object before saving it to the database and **[unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)** it when you return the query results.

Depending on how complex your class is that you use to instantiate the object, you might need to implement the [Serializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php) interface on your class.

Although, this is probably not good practice to store entire objects in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

follow this tested code..

```
 $obj = your object;
 $link= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","book_data");
 $query= "insert into tbbook (Booktitle ) values('$obj') where ID=1";
 mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

This code running perfectly.

1) Your data type of filed should be varchar.
2) Set size of colum according to length of object.